# Groovy JsonBuilder capitalising field names

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I'm using the Groovy JsonBuilder to generate JSON to send over HTTP.
My problem is it's capitalising some of the keys in the map it's given.

I give it an object of this class:

```
public class TestSNP {
    private String snpID;

    TestSNP(String input) {
        snpID = input.split("\\s+")[1];
    }

    String getSNPID() {
        return snpID;
    }
}
```

This is the test that fails:

```
import groovy.json.*

class Test {
    @Test
        void jsonBuilderTest() {
            def testSNP = new TestSNP("1 rs444444 2 3")
            assert new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(testSNP).toString() == '{"snpID":"rs444444"}'
        }
}
```

I get

```
{"SNPID":"rs444444"}
```

instead of

```
{"snpID":"rs444444"}
```

(this is a simplified example demonstrating my problem)

Comment: @tim_yates That would probably be useful, wouldn't it. I've added the line that's causing the trouble now. Thank you.

Comment: The answer is:  It doesn't...  Groovy is not capitalising the entries.  They will keep whatever capitalisation they have in the maps...  ie: `assert new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([[snps:[[snpID:'rs444444']]]]).toString() == '[{"snps":[{"snpID":"rs444444"}]}]'` will work fine in Groovy

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work. Indicating the problem is with my class, as:
assert new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([[snps:[new domain.SNP("1 rs444444 2 3")]]]).toString() == '[{"snps":[{"allele1":null,"position":2,"valid":true,"basePairCoordinate":3,"allele2":null,"snpID":"rs444444","chromasome":"1"}]}]'
doesn't work. I'll see if I can work out a simplified example that has the same problem, to save putting my whole class in here.

Comment: Is the field (or getter) in your `SNP` class called `SNPID` or `getSNPID`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. I worked it out while putting together the simplified example that's now in the question. I hadn't considered that it would have to use the getter, and therefore guess what conventions I was using for variable naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
String getSNPID() {
    return snpID;
}
```

to:

```
String getSnpID() {
    return snpID;
}
```

And it will work as you expect

Comment: It may also be worth noting that it also looks for isSomething() methods and will add a boolean "something" variable.

Comment: Yeah, it follows the Java Beans specification for getter naming :-)